# Comparing two dataframes in R and extract the values from one dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have two dataframes which have different number of rows and columns. one dataframe is with two columns and other dataframe with multiple columns.
The first dataframes looks like,

[image: The dataframe with item name and the value]

Second dataframe is like

[image: Dataframe with multiple columns not arranged in regular manner]

Actually, i need to replace the second dataframe which contains A,B,C etc with the values of 2nd column of first dataframe.

I need the output in below format.

[image: output format]

Help me to solve this problem.

dput:

df

```
structure(list(col1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", 
"I", "J", "K", "L"), col2 = c(10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 8, 19, 200, 
12, 112)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

df2

```
structure(list(col1 = c("A", "F", "W", "E", "F", "G"), col2 = c(NA, 
NA, "J", "K", "L", NA), col3 = c(NA, "H", "I", NA, "A", "B")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please code your data frames into the question

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner:

```r
as_tibble(`colnames<-`(matrix(df1$col2[match(as.matrix(df2),df1$col1)], ncol=3), names(df2)))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>    col1  col2  col3
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    10    NA    NA
#> 2     3    NA     8
#> 3    NA   200    19
#> 4     4    12    NA
#> 5     3   112    10
#> 6     1    NA     1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with a little data manipulation. Make the data in `df2` long, then join to `df`, then make the data wide again.

The `rowid_to_column` is necessary to make the transition from long to wide work. You can easily remove that column by adding `select(-rowid)` at the end of the chain.

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 %>%
    rowid_to_column() %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -rowid) %>%
    left_join(df, by = c("value" = "col1")) %>%
    select(-value) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = col2)

#   rowid  col1  col2  col3
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1    10    NA    NA
# 2     2     3    NA     8
# 3     3    NA   200    19
# 4     4     4    12    NA
# 5     5     3   112    10
# 6     6     1    NA     1
```

Answer (score 1):

one-liner in base R:

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(lapply(df2, function(x) ifelse(!is.na(x), setNames(df$col2, df$col1)[x], NA)))
```

**Output**

```
> df2
  col1 col2 col3
1   10   NA   NA
2    3   NA    8
3   NA  200   19
4    4   12   NA
5    3  112   10
6    1   NA    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another short one liner in *base*. You can use `match` and assign the result to `df2[]`:

```
df2[] <- df[match(unlist(df2), df[,1]), 2]
df2
#  col1 col2 col3
#1   10   NA   NA
#2    3   NA    8
#3   NA  200   19
#4    4   12   NA
#5    3  112   10
#6    1   NA    1
```